# Silvlerlight 4 development using VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, blend

My current software is based on Silverlight 3 and i am using VS 2008 and Blend 3 for development. With SL4 out in the wild, can i use my existing tool set (VS 2008 atleast) to develop SL4 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Silverlight 4 only works with Visual Studio 2010 and Blend 4.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it's possible:

> Ensure that you have the latest Visual
>   Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer
>   Express 2010 installed as it is a
>   prerequisite for developing
>   Silverlight 4 applications using
>   Visual Studio.

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4/